# Child view doesn't obtain size values

Tags: android, measurement

I have simple class `AppPopup` which extends FrameLayout.The class inflates its content and store it in content variable.I need content to be at the center of my popup's view.In order to measure content I override onMeasure, but height/width of the content equals -1 in this method

```
public class AppPopup extends FrameLayout {
    private View content;
    private View bg;
    public AppPopup(@NonNull Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public AppPopup(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public void setLayout(int resId) {
        LayoutInflater li=LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        bg=li.inflate(R.layout.popup_bg_fade,null);
        content=li.inflate(resId,null);
    }
    public void show() {
        addView(bg);
        addView(content);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        int heightSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
        int widthSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        Log.d("layout",content.getLayoutParams().width+","+content.getLayoutParams().height+","+(content.getParent()==this)); -1,-1,true
        content.setX(widthSize/2-content.getLayoutParams().width/2);
        content.setY(heightSize/2-content.getLayoutParams().height/2);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
        super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
        Log.d("layout",content.getLayoutParams().width+","+content.getLayoutParams().height+","+(content.getParent()==this)); //-1,-1,true
    }
}
```

I call it in the parent view:

```
AppPopup popup=new AppPopup(this);
root.addView(popup);
popup.setLayout(R.layout.gameover_popup1);
popup.show();
```

Within onLayout size also equals -1.But I can see my view on the screen with correct size.
I know I'm missing something simple but can't figure out what.

Answer (score 0):

int widthSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec); can be WRAP_CONTENT or MATCH_PARENT.

You can get just (works only after super.onMeasure since it setsMeasured after finishing):

```
int widthSize = getMeasuredWidth();
int heightSize = getMeasuredHeight();
```

For the child width after inflation you can call AFTER super.onLayout 
 child.getMeasuredWidth();

Comment: My question is how can I obtain size of the child view(content variable).I need it to align content inside my container view.There is no problem with detecting container size.

Comment: After onLayout you can call child.getMeasuredWidth();

Comment: It still returns container size.For some reason when I add content view to view hierarchy it expands to fullscreen like it has match_parent size but this is not true.It has fixed size.Anyway I managed to workaround by wrapping content into additional FrameLayout and setting wrap_content to this root layout.